# How to handle connection issues with kafka using the python kafka library?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

I have a serverless function that's trying to send some data to kafka. Sometimes it works and sometimes the connection just drop and the data is lost.

The reason for this is that the library for kafka is not raising the exception but it's adding error logs instead. So i cannot add my piece of code in a `try:except`.

Here is the error that i am often getting in my logs:

```
<BrokerConnection node_id=11 host=... port=9092>: Error receiving network data closing socket
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/kafka/conn.py", line 745, in _recv
data = self._sock.recv(SOCK_CHUNK_BYTES)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

and the function `_recv` mentioned above has definition as follows:

I am still looking for a solution but adding the code within try:except doesn't work.

```
def _recv(self):
        responses = []
        SOCK_CHUNK_BYTES = 4096
        while True:
            try:
                data = self._sock.recv(SOCK_CHUNK_BYTES)
                # We expect socket.recv to raise an exception if there is not
                # enough data to read the full bytes_to_read
                # but if the socket is disconnected, we will get empty data
                # without an exception raised
                if not data:
                    log.error('%s: socket disconnected', self)
                    self.close(error=Errors.ConnectionError('socket disconnected'))
                    break
                else:
                    responses.extend(self.receive_bytes(data))
                    if len(data) < SOCK_CHUNK_BYTES:
                        break
            except SSLWantReadError:
                break
            except ConnectionError as e:
                if six.PY2 and e.errno == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
                    break
                log.exception('%s: Error receiving network data'
                              ' closing socket', self)
                self.close(error=Errors.ConnectionError(e))
                break
            except BlockingIOError:
                if six.PY3:
                    break
                raise
        return responses
```

I expect when the connection is lost, an exception is raised and the application breaks but instead only there are only error logs and the application continues even if the kafka part fails.